# Сравнение временных переменных

Tags: переменные, java

Есть 2 переменные типа дата в формате "`mm:ss.d`", показывающие за сколько человек пробежал стометровку. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне их сравнить?

Comment: А что, стометровку кто-то  **минуты** бегает?

Comment: я конкретизировал для понятия вопроса)

Comment: Просто на практике можно взять начиная с *ss.d*, прочесть как float, и сравнивать их без проблем.

Comment: @avp: Ну, допустим, ТС моделирует Ахиллеса и черепаху :-)

Comment: @VladD, IMHO он вопросе указал только людей. 

Не, если хочется потренироваться с датами и десятыми секунды, то флаг в руки. В конце-концов лишних знаний не бывает.

Comment: @avp: хм, и правда, люди :-) Черепаха снимается с дистанции.

Answer (score 3):

> переменные типа дата в формате "mm:ss.d"

Пока они у вас в формате "mm:ss.d", это переменные типа String. Сконвертируйте в дату и сравнивайте две даты.

Если предстоит много возни с датами, удобно воспользоваться библиотекой [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Я так и сделал. неправильно выдает ответ.может кто попроще вариант предложит?)

Comment: Тогда ищите ошибку у себя, а не другой способ. Единственный правильный способ — сконвертировать в дату.

Comment: Я так подозреваю, что у вас неправильный формат при конфертировании даты.

"mm:ss.d" для Java значит "минуты:секунды.дни". Вы же, вероятно, хотите работать с форматом "mm:ss.S" или там "mm.ss:SSS". То есть после точки - миллисекунды.

Comment: Nofate,спасибо за верное замечание. Дело по-моему в том что я неправильно сравниваю

Comment: Nofate вы написали "mm:ss.S" или там "mm.ss:SSS".точки с запятыми правильно указали и там и там?

Comment: "mm:ss.S" конечно же. Хотя откуда мне знать, как оно там у вас ) Вы бы уже поделились своим "неправильным" кодом.

Comment: вот строка сравнения
if(date[i].before(datmax))
{
//
}

Answer (score 0):

Вроде не увидел такого варианта: просто перевести все в самую маленьку единицу измерения (если правильно понял то в микросекунды), перевести в целочисленный тип и сравнивать как хочеться)

P.S. перевести строку даты\времени известного формата - пара строк кода. И никаких библиотек